# Node.js: Two different applications competing to become servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, server, client

Good day, everyone.

I wanted to know if this was possible in Node.js. Suppose I have two different node applications, and they are both going to compete to be a server on a certain port. Whichever reaches the port first becomes the server, and the other one automatically becomes a client of that server.

Here is a simple diagram of what I am trying to explain:

[image]

So in this example, process 1 becomes the server because it reached the port first. Process 2 automatically becomes Process 1's client. However, I also want the functionality that if anything happens to Process 1 and the connection fails, then Process 2 becomes the new server on that same port.

Here is a diagram on what I mean:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var net = require('net');

var TIMEOUT_TIME = 3000; // in milliseconds
var PORT_NUMBER = 1337;

// Attempt to create server.
var application1 = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Hello Server 1\r\n');
  socket.end("hello");
  console.log("Someone connected to Server 1. \n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

application1.listen(PORT_NUMBER, function(){
    console.log("\nServer 1 is now the official server. \n");
    setTimeout(function() {
        application1.close();
        console.log("Server 1 has been closed.");
    }, TIMEOUT_TIME);
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('there was an error.');
    if(portIsUsed(err)) {
        console.log("Port Was In Use! (This is Server 1 trying to connect.)");
        net.connect(PORT_NUMBER, function() {
            console.log("Server 1 connected to port.\n");
        });
    }
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log("server 1 disconnected from port");
});

// Attempt to create server.
var application2 = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Hello Server 2\r\n');
  socket.end("hello");
  console.log("someone went into application2.");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

application2.listen(PORT_NUMBER, function() {
    console.log("\nServer 2 is now the official server. \n");
})
.on('error', function(err) {
    if(portIsUsed(err)) {
        console.log("Port Was In Use! (This is Server 2 trying to connect.)\n");
        net.connect(PORT_NUMBER, function() {
            console.log("Server 2 connected to port.\n");
        })
        .on("end", function() {
            // code here for when the connection ends?
        });
    }
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log("server 2 disconnected from port");
});


function portIsUsed(err) {
    return err.code === "EADDRINUSE";
}
```

Application2 successfully detects the EADDRINUSE error (because Application1 connects first, so the port is used), but how do I make become the new server in the case that Application1 drops? I tried using .on("end", ...) inside the .on("error",...) in application2, but its not working.

Is this even possible in Node.js, due to its single-threaded nature? In the Node API I saw that cluster was used to work on more than 1 thread if I had a multicore machine. Should I use that instead?

I'm new to Node.js, so any help pointing me the right way would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I saw You're trying to write same app twice to be able handle request and balance between them.
So thats solution:

write normal single-threaded app and then run it using pm2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2):

install

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

run

```
pm2 start app.js -i max
```

use keymetrics (https://keymetrics.io/):

```
pm2 interact public_key secret_key
```

doing app that trying to dominate on port is not good approach, even when You're switching roles from server to client.
it's better to know that one app runs on one port and another on second port and it's normal.